# Trying to echo out the value for slug but it doesn't work for some reason

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to call the value of taxonomyies->slug but for some reason, it doesn't work. Any idea why?

```
  @php
     $id = get_the_ID();
     $taxonomies = wp_get_post_terms( $id, 'section');
    @endphp
    <div class="container px-3">
     <div class="row pt-2">
      <div class="col">
       <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-5">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
         <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{site_url()}}">Home</a></li>
         <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" ><a href="{{site_url()}}/knowledge-base">Knowldege Base</a></li>
         <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" ><a href="{{site_url()}}/knowledge-base/@php  echo $taxonomies->slug @endphp ">Knowldege Base</a></li>
        </ol>
       </nav>
     <h1 class=" my-5 advcolor" >{{the_title()}}</h1>
                {{the_content()}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

wp_get_post_terms() returns an array of terms objects, so if you want to access the slug, maybe you can get for first term by $taxonomies[0]->slug.
Check this out for more information https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/